# ASP.NET MVC: Problem generating thumbnails...need help!

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, image, thumbnails

Ok, so i'm new to asp.net mvc and i'm trying to make a web application photo gallery.  I've posted once on here about this issue i am having of trying to generate thumbnails on-the-fly on the page instead of the actual full-size images.  Basically, the functionality i am looking for is to be able to have thumbnails on the page and then be able to click the images to see the full-size version.  I am pulling the images and images info from an XML file.  So, i did this so i could display them dynamically and so it would be easier to make changes later.  Later, i am going to add functionality to upload new images to specific galleries (when i figure out how to do that as well).  I am providing a link to download the project i am working on so you can see the code.  I would appreciate any help with this!  Thanks!
URL to project: http://www.diminished4th.com/TestArtist.zip
Ryan

Comment: Dear lord man, make friends with your return key.

Answer (score 1):

In your global.asax.cs file, you have defined the *Default* route before your *Thumbs* route so the Galleries part of the url is mapped to a non-existent Galleries controller instead of the Gallery controller (as specified in your second route):

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default", // Route name
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
     new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
);

routes.MapRoute(
    "Thumbs", // Route name
    "Galleries/getThumb/{image}", // URL with parameters
     new { controller = "Gallery", action = "getThumb", id = UrlParameter.Optional }, // Parameter defaults
      new string[] { "TestArtist.Controllers" }
 );
```

Simply define the *Thumbs* route before the *Default* route and you should be all good:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Thumbs", // Route name
    "Galleries/getThumb/{image}", // URL with parameters
     new { controller = "Gallery", action = "getThumb", id = UrlParameter.Optional }, // Parameter defaults
      new string[] { "TestArtist.Controllers" }
 );

routes.MapRoute(
    "Default", // Route name
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
     new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
);
```